# Yakuake always covers the whole screen

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro

I maximised Yakuake by mistake using shortcuts and now, even if I terminate the program, even if I reset my computer, it's always maximised.

If I try minimising with shortcuts, it's not the original deal and when it loses focus it opens maximised. I should emphasise, it is not in full screen.

I've also tried reinstalling it, twice.

I realise it has to do with the OS in itself, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try the following (works for some applications):  Set Yakuake the way you want. Do not close it. Log off the operating system leaving Yakuake open while you log off. Log on and see if Yakuake is behaving the way you wish. Make sure it has not files open while you log off.

Comment: I can't set it the way I want. It's covering my whole screen and when I resize it it loses its menus and whatever.

Comment: Check against [post1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=69831) and [post2](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=134945).

Comment: It's different. But I managed to solve it finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yakuake menu provides `width` and `height` options that can be adjusted to one's preferences.

Thank you everyone.